# Assigning a variable in make

Tags: makefile, variable-assignment, gnu-make

I have the following in a makefile

```
ifneq ($(GIT_INFO),)
$(info $(GIT_INFO))
GIT_INFO:=Changed
$(info $(GIT_INFO))
endif
```

Where, my desire is that if `GIT_INFO` was set to something on the command line, its value gets populated with the desired string (specifics unimportant).  I added the `$(info..)` lines to verify that this piece was being executed, and it was, but that the value of `GIT_INFO` wasn't getting changed, and it isn't.  Why not?  I pass `GIT_INFO=true` on the command line, and both places print `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `override`:

```
ifneq ($(GIT_INFO),)
$(info $(GIT_INFO))
override GIT_INFO:=Changed
$(info $(GIT_INFO))
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive),

> If a variable has been set with a command argument..., then ordinary assignments in the makefile are ignored. If
>   you want to set the variable in the makefile even though it was set
>   with a command argument, you can use an override directive...

Just add `override`:

```
ifneq ($(GIT_INFO),)
$(info $(GIT_INFO))
override GIT_INFO:=Changed
$(info $(GIT_INFO))
endif
```